# Retrieve the values of a nested list from JSP and send it back to form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, struts

**EDIT** Now I know my problem is due to [this](https://wiki.apache.org/struts/StrutsCatalogLazyList). The link also provided solutions but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in the 2nd list.

I will first show you the code structure I am working on.

Here is Class MyForm:

```
public class MyForm extends ValidatorForm {
    private List<ADTO> aDTOList;

    // getters and setters for aDTOList below

    public ADTO getADTO(int index) {
        if (aDTOList == null) {
            aDTOList = new ArrayList<ADTO>();
        }
        if (aDTOList.size() - 1 < index) {
            while (aDTOList.size() - 1 < index) {
                aDTOList.add(new ADTO());
            }
        }
        return aDTOList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    protected ActionErrors execValidate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
          // BODY NOT SHOWN FOR PRIVACY
    }

    @Override
    public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) { 
        super.reset(mapping, request);
        this.aDTOList = new ArrayList<ADTO>();
    }


}
```

Here is Class ADTO:

```
public class ADTO {
    private List<BDTO> bDTOList;
    // getters and setters for bDTOList below

}
```

Here is Class BDTO:

```
public class BDTO {
    private String sample1;
    private String sample2;
    // getters and setters for sample1 and sample2 below

}
```

I have successfully displayed the contents of `aDTOList` in the JSP by doing this:

```
<logic:iterate id="ADTO" name="MyForm" property="aDTOList" indexId="idxRes">
    <logic:iterate id="BDTO" name="ADTO" property="bDTOList" indexId="idxLine">
        <html:hidden name="BDTO" property="sample1" indexed="true"/>
        <html:hidden name="BDTO" property="sample2" indexed="true"/>
    </logic:iterate>
</logic:iterate>
```

Now my problem is whenever I submit the form `bDTOList` that is inside `aDTOList` will become all null.`aDTOList` has the same size as the original list I have displayed but the only difference is that all elements of `bDTOList` in a `aDTO` is null. The structure of the `aDTOList` is like this if the size of `aDTOList` is 2 and each `ADTO` contains `bDTOList` which also has the size of 2.

```
[[null, null],[null, null]]
```

Thus I think my problem is I do not have `getBDTO` in my form, but I don't know how to implement it. Can anyone help me on how to implement it? Or is there any other means of populating `bDTOList` with the original data?

**NOTE: I CAN'T CHANGE THE STRUCTURE OF THE CODES AND THE CODES ARE JUST SAMPLE CODES**

Comment: Have you tried giving a value = "" field in your html:hidden attribute?

Comment: The html:hidden attribute will render into an input attribute and the input attribute has the actual value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After days of research and tinkering my code I finally was able to retrieve back the values from the JSP and send it back to form. I will just post an answer for future reference. Thanks to [this website](https://wiki.apache.org/struts/StrutsCatalogLazyList) I was able to know the cause of my problem and eventually made a solution to solve it. Refer below on the details on how I solved my problem.

I found out that the problem is due to an issue in Commons BeanUtils with indexed properties if you use java.util.List rather than Arrays is that people then get "index out of range" errors with ActionForms that are in Request scope. That is why growing the list when the get(int) method is called is needed to be done. Also you need to reinitialize the list whenever the reset method is called. To do this you need to paste this code in the reset method of the form:

```
public void reset(ActionMapping actionMapping, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

    aDTOList = ListUtils.lazyList(new java.util.ArrayList(), new Factory() {
        public Object create() {
            return buildADTOList();
        }
    });
 }

private ADTO buildADTOList() {
    ADTO aDTO = new ADTO();
    List bDTOList = ListUtils.lazyList(new java.util.ArrayList(), new Factory() {
        public Object create() {
            return new BDTO();
        }
    });
    aDTO.setBDTOList(bDTOList);
    return aDTO;
}
```

Now your whenever the reset method is called your list will regrow to its original size. The next problem is now how to retrieve back the values from the JSP and place them back in the list. To do this you have to take note of that the value of the resulting html name attribute of your JSP tag must be in this format `aDTOList[0].bDTOList[0].sample1`. But if you use  tag (just as the question was using), the value of the resulting html will look like this:
Example:

```
<logic:iterate id="ADTO" name="MyForm" property="aDTOList" indexId="idxRes">
    <logic:iterate id="BDTO" name="ADTO" property="bDTOList" indexId="idxLine">
        <html:hidden name="BDTO" property="sample1" indexed="true"/>
        <html:hidden name="BDTO" property="sample2" indexed="true"/>
    </logic:iterate>
</logic:iterate>
```

This will result into:

```
<input type="hidden" name="BDTO[0].sample1" value="..."/>
<input type="hidden" name="BDTO[0].sample2" value="..."/>
<input type="hidden" name="BDTO[1].sample1" value="..."/>
<input type="hidden" name="BDTO[1].sample2" value="..."/>
<input type="hidden" name="BDTO[0].sample1" value="..."/>
<input type="hidden" name="BDTO[0].sample2" value="..."/>
<input type="hidden" name="BDTO[1].sample1" value="..."/>
<input type="hidden" name="BDTO[1].sample2" value="..."/>
```

The result is not in `aDTOList[0].bDTOList[0].sample1` format thus you need to use `<nested:iterate>`.
The converted code will be:

```
<nested:iterate property="aDTOList" indexId="idxRes">
    <nested:iterate property="bDTOList" indexId="idxLine">
        <nested:hidden property="sample1"/>
        <nested:hidden property="sample2"/>
    </nested:iterate>
</nested:iterate>
```

This will result to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="aDTOList[0].bDTOList[0].sample1" value="..."/>
<input type="hidden" name="aDTOList[0].bDTOList[0].sample2" value="..."/>
<input type="hidden" name="aDTOList[0].bDTOList[1].sample1" value="..."/>
<input type="hidden" name="aDTOList[0].bDTOList[1].sample2" value="..."/>
<input type="hidden" name="aDTOList[1].bDTOList[0].sample1" value="..."/>
<input type="hidden" name="aDTOList[1].bDTOList[0].sample2" value="..."/>
<input type="hidden" name="aDTOList[1].bDTOList[1].sample1" value="..."/>
<input type="hidden" name="aDTOList[1].bDTOList[1].sample2" value="..."/>
```

As you can see it is in `aDTOList[0].bDTOList[0].sample1` format.

And from that you can retrieve the values of a nested list from JSP and send it back to form. I hope this will serve as a guide for those people that have been stuck for days solving this kind of problem.

Answer (score -1):

From the link you provided, you are using Struts 1. Here is how I do it in my project:

**Form**
Similar to your code, declare a `List` in the container action form. And need one additional important configuration for the list, need to override the `reset` method of `ActionForm` to initiate the `List` with empty objects. The `reset` code is like below:

```java
// Form Class
  ....
  // Declare the list
  private List<DetailDto> details = new ArrayList<>();
  ....
  // Reset Method
  private Pattern detailParameterPattern = Pattern.compile("details\\[(\\d+)\\].*");
  private static final int FIRST_GROUP_INDEX = 1;

  @Override
  public void reset(ActionMapping actionMapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
    super.reset(actionMapping, request);
    Enumeration<String> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
    int maxSize = 0;
    boolean matched = false;
    while (paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
      String paramName = paramNames.nextElement();
      Matcher detailMatcher = detailParameterPattern.matcher(paramName);
      if (detailMatcher.matches()) {
        matched = true;
        String index = detailMatcher.group(FIRST_GROUP_INDEX);
        if (Integer.parseInt(index) > maxSize) {
          maxSize = Integer.parseInt(index);
        }
      }
    }
    if (matched) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= maxSize; i++) {
        details.add(new DetailDto());
      }
    }
  }
```

**JSP**
There is a `indexed` attribute of Struts `html` tags. With **JSTL** `forEach` tag, declare the `items` and variable, the variable name should be little tricky that it should be same as the name you declared in form. The code looks like below:

```
<c:forEach items="${form.details}" varStatus="detailsStatus" var="details">
    <tr>
        <td class="resultCell">${detailsStatus.index+1}</td>
        <td class="resultCell">
           <html:checkbox name="details" property="checked" indexed="true" value="Y"/>
....
...
```

The others value mapping are done automatically by Struts framework.
The key here is that you need to initiate the `List`(Or `Array`) with objects instead of empty `List`(Or `Array`), because Struts cannot create object for it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I already solved it. Also I am not allowed to use ```<c:forEach>``` tags. And sadly I don't understand your answer, but I noticed that you are only iterating a list which is not my question is all about. The question is on nested list.