# How to submit two dimentional array in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, submit

I'm trying to submit form which contains two dimentional array. Can You check my code and tell me what's wrong with it?

Form:

```java
public class SimpleForm {

    private String[][] twoDimentionArray;

    public String[][] getTwoDimentionArray() {
        return twoDimentionArray;
    }

    public void setTwoDimentionArray(String[][] twoDimentionArray) {
        this.twoDimentionArray = twoDimentionArray;
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/save-form} th:object="${form}" method="post"> 

    <input type="text" th:field="*{twoDimentionArray[0][0]}"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Following error occures:

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: array element type mismatch
    at java.lang.reflect.Array.set(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processKeyedProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:311) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:275) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:266) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:97) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:839) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:735) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your array wrong. Try this

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/save-form}" th:object="${form}" method="post"> 
    <div th:each="1d, i: *{twoDimentionArray}">
        <div th:each="test, j: *{1d}">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{userAddresses[__${i.index}__][__${j.index}__]}" />
       </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. Array from my example is already initialized and filled in controller. What is more there is no problem with one dimentional array, even if it was not initialized.

Comment: @polishgrand If I solved your problem don't forget to mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: unfortunately problem still exists, initialization of array is not a solution of the problem

Comment: Why would you not make it as a List of List?

Comment: because in my case functionality is strictly connected with indexes

Comment: Try my solution

Comment: as I said, initialization of array doesn't work. List of list is not solution for me, so case is still open.

Comment: I have edited my answer, also you could refer to this maybe it will give you an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272358/retrieve-the-values-of-a-nested-list-from-jsp-and-send-it-back-to-form